# Is it possible to recreate the .meteor directory?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I tried to run my Meteor app from its directory with the "meteor" command, I got, "You're not in a Meteor project directory."

When I looked, I saw that the .meteor folder got deleted; I guess I somehow inadvertently did that.

Is there a way to add back a corrupted or deleted .Meteor folder?

Comment: This may be a silly question, but are you using some kind of version control?

Comment: Not really; I did copy the entire folder to a backup folder, and then copy that to skydrive; however, before copying, I delete the humongous (no pun intended) .meteor folder. Apparently I accidentally deleted the one from the project folder rather than the one from the backup location! I hate it when I do that.

Comment: I was able to copy the previously backed up .meteor folder to there and have it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but there shouldn't be anything in there that cannot be recreated easily.
I'd `meteor create DoinItAgain` in a new directory, then copy all your source files into the new project.
Then it's time to play ['Whack a Mole'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkEW7.jpg) with the errors that come up, due to packages that will need to be re-added to the project.

Comment: I think I'll rename the existing project with an underscore in front of it, create it again in the same place (try to, that is), and then copy everything over; and add back the packages I'm using (iron:router, bootstrap, and dburles:googlemaps or something like that.